# Need to remove domains domains from sub-domans

Tags: linux, bash, awk, cut, tr

I am trying to get last 2 values from right to left from cut command

I have a large database for about 110 Million domains and subdomains.

Like

```
yahoo.com
mail.yahoo.com
a.yahoo.com
a.yahoo.co.uk
```

In simple words I am trying to remove subdomains from domains

```
echo a.yahoo.aa | cut -d '.' -f 2,3
yahoo.aa
```

but when I try

```
echo yahoo.aa | cut -d '.' -f 2,3
aa
```

it give me only  `aa`

Required output is

```
yahoo.com
yahoo.com
yahoo.com
yahoo.co.uk
```

> edit thanks anubhava for suggestion.

a TLD property is like

```
xxxx.xx
xxx.xx
xx.xx
```

i.e. a ccTLD always has 2 characters in last.

Comment: What about `sub.yahoo.co.uk` ?

Comment: _I am trying to get last 2 values from right to left from cut command_: So, why do you keep `yahoo` in `a.yahoo.co.uk`? This is not _last 2 values_ it is _last 3 values_, isn't it? What's the logic here?

Answer (score 1):

Long solution but a think that makes what you want to do:

Executable file `domain.awk`:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS="."
}
{
    ret = $NF
    if (NF >= 2 && (length($(NF - 1)) == 2 || length($(NF - 1)) == 3)) {
        ret = $(NF - 1) "." ret
        if (NF >= 3) {
            ret = $(NF - 2) "." ret
        }
    } else if (NF >= 2) {
        ret = $(NF - 1) "." ret
    }
    print ret
}
```

with `domains.lst` file:

```
yahoo.com
mail.yahoo.com
a.yahoo.com
a.yahoo.co.uk
aus.co.au
```

Used like that:

```bash
./domain.awk domains.lst
```

Output:

```
yahoo.com
yahoo.com
yahoo.com
yahoo.co.uk
aus.co.au
```

Comment: You posted the wrong output

Answer (score 1):

Using the sample input you provided and accepting your statement that `a ccTLD always has 2 characters in last.` as being your criteria for printing the last 3 instead of last 2 segments of the input:

Using GNU grep for `-o`:

```
$ grep -Eo '[^.]+\.[^.]+(\.[^.]{2})?$' file
yahoo.com
yahoo.com
yahoo.com
yahoo.co.uk
```

or using any awk:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/[^.]+\.[^.]+(\.[^.]{2})?$/){print substr($0,RSTART)}' file
yahoo.com
yahoo.com
yahoo.com
yahoo.co.uk
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo a.yahoo.aa | awk -F'.' '{print $NF"."$(NF-1)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

> large database for about 110 Million domains and subdomains.

Due to this I suggest using `sed` here, let `file.txt` content be

```
yahoo.com
mail.yahoo.com
a.yahoo.com
```

then

```
sed 's/^.*\.\([^.]*\.[^.]*\)$/\1/' file.txt
```

output

```
yahoo.com
yahoo.com
yahoo.com
```

Explanation: In regular expression spanning whole line (`^`-start, `$`-end) I use single capturing group which contain zero-or-more (`*`) non-dots followed by literal dot (`\.`) followed by zero-or-more non-dots which is adjacent to end of line, I replace whole line with content of that group. **Disclaimer**: this solution assumes there is always at least one dot in each line

*(tested in GNU sed 4.2.2)*

Comment: Somehow it work... but domains like aus.co.au show me co.au only... any possible way we can sort this as well..

Answer (score -1):

You are selecting only fields 2 and 3. You need to select from field 2 up to the end:

```
 ... | cut -d '.' -f 2-
```